# Add video to existing call with CallKit from incall screen menu

Tags: ios, callkit

We are using CallKit in our iOS 10 VoIP app. We have noticed that when on a call managed by CallKit, tapping the incall Video button sends a StartCallIntent and so starts a new video call. What we require is to add video to the existing call. So we really need a callback method just as the Mute, Hold and Group buttons call various methods. But there is no callback for the incall Video button.

Anyone know how to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just ignore the intent and show video since your app is now in the foreground?

Comment: But how do I know its for that existing call and which call UUID? The other buttons on the incall screen trigger callbacks to which the call UUID is passed.

Comment: One approach would be to inspect the CXHandle on the CXStartCallAction upon receiving it, and check whether that handle corresponds to an audio call already in progress in your app. If there is already an audio call to that handle, you may assume that the CXStartCallAction represents an "upgrade" to video, then you can transfer the existing audio call to an audio+video call and continue from there.

Comment: We don't get a CXStartCallAction when tapping the video button, we get INStartAudioCallIntent, so we can only get the dialled number from this. As you mentioned we can compare this dialled number with any audio calls we have ongoing. We don't think thats ideal but without the UUID to the call its the best we can do.